# How to group in pandas dataframe by value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

| id | action | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | go | 3 |
| 1 | click | 0 |
| 1 | search | 0 |
| 1 | search | 0 |
| 1 | go | 3 |
| 1 | click | 0 |

And I want to split it into groups of actions, where **each group should begins from** **action** **go**. For this example I will have two groups.

What are the ways to do it in pandas?

Comment: `df.groupby(df["action"].eq("go").cumsum())`

Comment: What is your desirde output??